# Why is the mitzvah of Hakhel not observed at this time?

Tags: contemporary-halacha, hakhel, observance

Based on [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/131344/27180), I'm interested in the fact that nowadays, the mitzvah of Hakhel seems not to be observed as it was back then when the Holy Temple still stood.

Is the mitzvah of Hakhel bound to when the Beis HaMikdosh is standing, or are there other reasons why this mitzvah is not observed as back in the days?

I'm looking for (contemporary) commentaries that discuss this issue.

Comment: The verse quoted there says "when all Yisrael is come to appear before the L-rd thy G-d in the place which he shall choose". Does that happen nowadays?

Comment: Commemorating _Hakhel_ in modern times: [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakhel#Twentieth-century_revival), and [in Peninei Halakha](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/13-08-05/).

Comment: @DoubleAA Right, so this mitzvah is dependent on whether we are living in Eretz Yisroel as a "whole" or not?

Comment: @TamirEvan Thank you. The second one is what I was looking for. It describes that the mitzvah of hakhel is bound to the Beis Hamikdosh and therefore we cannot observe it as it was back then. So, based on what Double AA and you wrote, this mitzvah will be observed in its fullest when Moshiach comes, right?

Comment: @Shmuel "_So, based on what Double AA and you wrote, this mitzvah will be observed in its fullest when Moshiach comes, right?_" That would be my understanding, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sefer HaChinukh, in mitzvah 612](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.612.5?lang=bi), writes that the mitzvah of Hakhel is bound to whether the Jewish people are settled in Eretz Yisrael.

> This commandment is practiced at the time when Israel is on their land.